# How to modify X axis labels when there are multiple variables in X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Firstly, on the 1st row of X-axis, I have got labels like "white.highinc" that is the income for race white, but I have already a category for income level, so I just want the labels to be like white, black etc. for each set of columns.

Second, when I use "scale_fill_manual" function to get different colours for each year, the R shows "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale". But in my data frame YEAR is discrete not continuous. In my data frame there are only three years 1995, 2005 and 2010. What should I do?

```
ggplot(data = data1, aes(x = interaction(race_code, inc_level, lex.order = TRUE), y = percent_lwpr, group = YEAR, fill=YEAR)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width=0.8)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#ffa600", "#ff6361", "#bc5090"))+
  facet_grid(~inc_level, switch = "x", scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

[mygraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W877u.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. If you want to post your data type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 10))` for the first ten rows of data.

Comment: ... this said. The issue with `scale_fill_manual` could be fixed by converting your YEAR column (which is a numeric) to a discrete variable, e.g. do `..., aes(..., fill = factor(YEAR))`.

Comment: @stefan thank you. do you have any solution for the first problem?

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue with the labels you could pass a function to the `labels` argument of `scale_x_discrete` which using `gsub` removes the unwanted part of the label starting with the `.`.

Using a subset of the `ggplot2::mpg` dataset as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

mpg2 <- mpg[mpg$manufacturer %in% c("audi", "volkswagen"), ]

ggplot(mpg2, aes(interaction(class, manufacturer, lex.order = TRUE), fill = factor(year))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ gsub("\\..*$", "", .x)) +
  facet_grid(~manufacturer, switch = "x", scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]